# mat-radio-group is not known with Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have upgraded from Angular 2 to Angular 9 and now I get the following error:

```
src/app/contact-list/contact-list.component.html:7:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-radio-group' is 
not a known element:
1. If 'mat-radio-group' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-radio-group' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

7     <mat-radio-group>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Actually it is not clear for me why this error occures - I have a material.module.ts file:

```
@NgModule({ 
imports: [MatListModule, MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, 
MatCheckboxModule, MatRadioModule, MatSelectModule, MatDatepickerModule, 
MatNativeDateModule, MatDialogModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatIcon, 
MatCardModule, MatProgressBarModule ],
exports: [MatListModule, MatButtonModule, MatToolbarModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, 
MatCheckboxModule, MatRadioModule, MatSelectModule, MatDatepickerModule, 
MatNativeDateModule, MatDialogModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatIcon, 
MatCardModule, MatProgressBarModule ]
})

export class MaterialModule { 
}
```

so MatRadioModule must be known.
Does anyone know what I have to do in order to get it work also with Angular 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**import `MatRadioModule` in you app module!**

angular material seperated all of the components to sepeate modules for perforamance improvement.

so if you want to use radio button component in your application, you need to import that module first

Comment: Could you provide the sample code? Because with Angular 9, MatRadioModule  is importing from @angular/material/radio and I am still getting the error!